# Now that I've beaten the game, should I play again in Hard Mode?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've beaten the game, and now I feel kind of empty.

And, I seem to have lost my old save states, restoring from slot 1 one gives me an almost empty state (40 candies or so).

It seems now to be possible to play the game on hard mode.

Is it just harder or do new game play elements pop up?

Comment: The question is about the changes on the hard mode?

Comment: You celebrate with a cold glass of beer and play hard mode or look for a new free to play game.

Comment: [A Dark Room](http://adarkroom.doublespeakgames.com/) is a neat free game in a similar vein, and gets name checked in candybox 2.  :)

Comment: Yes, I should have split it in three questions: 1. Is there hidden more than just a repeat of the same on hard mode? 2. Is the save mechanism broken/buggy? 3. What is different in hard mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play hard mode, but the only difference is that you can't get more health by eating candy.  It's quite interesting though.

Comment: That is what i have started to suspect after wasting A LOT of candies.